# How to get the size of the drawing area of a Windows Form?

Tags: winforms, size

How does one get the size of the drawing area in a Windows Form?

The Size, Width and Height properties return it for the entire form, whereas I'm looking for the area marked in the linked diagram by the white arrows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQueF.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the .ClientRectangle property.  That has the dimensions you're looking for.